# Adding markers to openlayers

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

I have a map where users should be able to click where they want and a marker will be added, when they add a new marker, a line will connect to the previous one creating a route. The route doesn't have to follow roads or anything, just a straight line connecting the points.

So far I have this code where the idea would be that users click on the map, a marker appears and it is stored so that it can be removed later or so that the route can be saved to load it later:

```
const markers = [];
const view = new View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [-3.704322881508588, 40.4074397621576],
    zoom: 12,
    extent: [-9.844, 35.747, 4.878, 43.993],
  });

let map = new Map({
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM(),
      }),
    ],
    keyboardEventTarget: document,
    target: 'mapa',
    view: view,
    controls: defaultControls().extend([new ZoomSlider()]),
});
map.on('click', function(evt){
  console.info(evt.pixel);
  console.info(map.getPixelFromCoordinate(evt.coordinate));
  console.info(evt.coordinate);
  var coords = evt.coordinate;
  var lat = coords[1];
  var lon = coords[0];
  var locTxt = "Latitude: " + lat + " Longitude: " + lon;
  
  let marker = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
        ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat])
    ),
  });
  
  marker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
        src: "/imgs/chincheta.png",
    })
  }));
  markers.push(marker);
  let capa = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
          features: markers, 
      }),
  });
  
  map.addLayer(capa);
});
```

The HTML just has a div "mapa" and the reference to this script like this: `<script type="module" src="js/mapa.mjs"></script>`.
The problem is that it does not let me add any marker, if I change `markers` with `marker` in the line `features: markers,` it throws an error: i.getArray is not a function so I don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: Maybe this [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_7.3.0_addMarkerOnClick.html) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up with:

```
let draw;
let dibujo;
let coordinates = [];
let old_coordinates = [];
let map;

// Layer for drawing waypoints.
const drawVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({ wrapX: false }),
    style: function (feature) {
        return style[feature.get("type")] || style.line;
    },
});

// Style for the markers and the lines connecting them
const style = {
    // Waypoints style
    marker: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            anchor: [0.5, 1],
            src: "imgs/marker.png",
        }),
    }),
    // Line style
    line: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 2
        })
    })
};

function init() {
    // Layer that shows a map made from raster tiles from the server.
    const raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: 'imgs/sat_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' // Ruta donde se encuentran los archivos tiles descargados
        }),
    });
    // This layer restricts the area where you are allowed to draw
    var limite = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector(),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: "red",
                width: 2,
                opacity: 1,
            }),
        }),
    });
    // This Feature draws the restricted area using the points from limites which is an array formed by the waypoints that limits the area, you need at least three.
    var limiteFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([limites]),
    });
    limite.getSource().addFeature(limiteFeature);
    // Layer for drawing on the map.
    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: drawVector.getSource(),
        type: 'LineString',
        freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.never,
        finishCondition: ol.events.condition.never,
    });
    // Map with all the layers created plus another one for "static waypoints" that the user cannot change.
    map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, limite, staticVector, drawVector],
        keyboardEventTarget: document,
        target: "mapa",
        //Centramos la vista en el aeropuerto y limitamos la vista a España
        view: new ol.View({
            projection: "EPSG:4326",
            // This would determine the center point at the start and the maximum area visible at minimum zoom (censored just in case).
            center: [XX.XXXXX, XX.XXXXX],
            extent: [XX.XXXXX, XX.XXXXX, XX.XXXXX, XX.XXXXX],
            zoom: 16
        }),
    });
    // And here is what happens when you click on the map to add waypoints
    map.on("click", function (evt) {
        // I have a drawing mode so that you do not add waypoints by accident, just when you have clicked the option to add them.
        if (dibujo == true) {
            //Check restricted area
            var esIncluido = limiteFeature.getGeometry().intersectsCoordinate(evt.coordinate); 
            if (esIncluido) {
                // If the point is create the marker.
                point = new ol.geom.Point(evt.coordinate);
                marker = new ol.Feature({
                    type: "marker",
                    geometry: point,
                });
                // Save the point
                coordinates.push(marker);
                // Clear the array used for redoing deleted points.
                old_coordinates = [];
                // Place marker on the map
                drawVector.getSource().addFeature(marker);
            } else {
                // The point is added even when clicking outside of the allowed area so if it was not allowed we remove it.
                draw.removeLastPoint();
            }
        }
    });
}
// Enter the waypoints or drawing mode:
function waypoints() {
    dibujo = true;
    map.addInteraction(draw)
    // Delete what was drawn previosly
    drawVector.getSource().clear();
    drawVector.getSource().clear();
    coordinates = [];
    old_coordinates = [];
}
// Clear the drawing
function waypointsClear() {
    draw.abortDrawing();
    drawVector.getSource().clear();
    coordinates = [];
    old_coordinates = [];
    dibujo = true;
    save = false;
    map.addInteraction(draw)
}
// Remove the last waypoint.
function waypointsUndo() {
    if (save == false) {
        draw.removeLastPoint();
        const lastCoord = coordinates.pop();
        drawVector.getSource().removeFeature(lastCoord);
        old_coordinates.push(lastCoord);
        drawVector.getSource().changed();
    }
}
// Redo the last undoed waypoint
function waypointsRedo() {
    if (old_coordinates.length > 0 && save == false) {
        let last = old_coordinates.pop();
        draw.appendCoordinates([last.getGeometry().getCoordinates()]);
        drawVector.getSource().addFeature(last);
        coordinates.push(last);
    }
}
```

This code allows to place markers and connect them with a line and doing some other things with them.